# How to read particular text from file in C#

Tags: c#

HI,
I am in learning process of C# and trying to read file in my application.But i dont want to read complete file i simply want to read particular text from that file and want to display that text in textbox....
can any please help me in that i want to know the method i can use for reading particular text from file..

Thanks in Advance

Parag Deshpande

Comment: You need to have some rules to identify the particular piece of text - for example, 20th line, text starting at 134 characters or text followed by @@ etc.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming these are text files, just open the file and read through it searching for whatever you're searching for.  When you find it, stop reading though it.  The [`File.ReadLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) will do this for you and will not read the entire file at the start but give you lines as it goes through it.

```
var filename = @"c:\path\to\my\file.txt";
var searchTarget = "foo";
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    if (line.Contains(searchTarget))
    {   // found it!
        // do something...

        break; // then stop
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you're not using C# 4.0, use a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and you can still accomplish the same thing in mostly the same way.  Again, read up until you find your line, do something and then stop.

```
string line = null;
using (var reader in new StreamReader(filename))
{
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(searchTarget))
        {   // found it!
            // do something...

            break; // then stop
        }
    }
}
```

If you are searching for a specific pattern and not just a particular word, you'd need to use regular expressions in conjunction with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning, its best to read the whole file with str = IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName) and then just locate what you want inside the string. to read a part of the text you need to use StreamReader and is much more complex.

Comment: Unfortunately as the name suggests, it reads the entire file into memory.

Comment: didn't knew about ReadLines.. simple and fast, +1 for you :)

Answer (score 1):

normally, we need to read every line one by one. some codes like below:

```
try {
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\abc.txt", FileMode.Open)) {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8)) {
            string line = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                if (line.Contains("keyword")) {

                }
                // or using Regex
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"^pattern$");
                if (regex.IsMatch(line)) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read from a particular position. You would have to read in the entire content, discard the portion that you don't need and read until you read the desired location.

On additional note, since you said you would like to populate textbox, it maybe idea to consider some sort of XML file that contains desired values for individual textboxes.